# SpringBoot: dinamically set properties in application.yaml

Tags: spring, properties

application.yaml containts (for example) the settings:

```
 spring.cloud.stream:
    kafka.streams.binder.functions.filter:
       applicationId: zk
```

I want "applicationId" to be set dinamically.
For this aim I tried to use SpEl. But turn out SpEl could not be applicable to apllication.yaml.

I read about 2 ways of dinamically settings of yaml:

1. Using pom.xml
2. Using environment variables

But this ways not applicable to my situation: its a gradle-project. All instances of application deployed from one container.

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.cloud.stream:
    kafka.streams.binder.functions.filter:
       applicationId: ${zk_prop:zk}
```

Where `zk_prop` is the env variable and `zk` the default value.

To pass arguments while running your application using Gradle Plugin, you need to configure the bootRun task in build.gradle file like:

```
bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        args project.args.split(',')
    }
}
```

Now, you can pass the command-line arguments as follows:

`./gradlew bootRun -Pargs=--zk_prop=custom-zk,--other_props=...`

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you